# Removing service from Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-service

I had installed and later uninstalled SQL Server 2005 . I used registry cleaner tools and deleted all files related to SQL Server . 
Still the services console shows entry for previous installed database instance name .
Services management console I get this entry in Description column.
*`Failed to Read Description Error code 2`*

How to delete them otherwise new installtion is showing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Open cmd as administrator

```
sc delete servicename
```

2- open run > regedit , back it up first and then browse to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services

and delete the service key

3- reboot the machine

Comment: worked PERFECTLY..actually I did `sc delete servicename` , but didn't know about registry keys . also rebooting is must to see changes . Thanks a lot !!!